# How replace whitespaces (unicode to utf-8) with a regex C#

Tags: c#, regex, unicode, replace

I'm trying to do a replace regex in C #. The method that I'm trying to write replace some unicode character (spaces) by normal space in UTF-8.

Let me explain with code. I'm not good writting regular expressions, culture information and regex.

```
    //This method replace white spaces in unicode by whitespaces UTF-8
    public static string cleanUnicodeSpaces(string value)
    {
        //This first pattern works but, remove other special characteres
        //For example: mark accents
        //string pattern = @"[^\u0000-\u007F]+"; 
        string cleaned = ""; 
        string pattern = @"[^\u0020\u0009\u000D]+"; //Unicode characters
        string replacement = ""; //Replace by UTF-8 space
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
        cleaned = regex.Replace(value, replacement).Trim(); //Trim by quit spaces
        return cleaned;
    }
```

**Unicode spaces**

- HT:U+0009 = Character tabulation
- LF:U+000A = Line Feed
- CR:U+000D = Carriage Return

What I doing wrong?

**Source**

1. Unicode Characteres: https://unicode-table.com/en
2. White Spaces:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character
3. Regex: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx

*SOLUTION*
Thanks to @wiktor-stribiżew and @mathias-r-jessen, solution:

```
 string pattern = @"[\u0020\u0009\u000D\u00A0]+";
 //I include \u00A0 for replace &nbsp
```

Comment: Remove `^` from the character class

Comment: _string replacement = "";_ I can't see a space here.

Comment: You return `value`. That is the same thing you pass in. Make sure you return `cleaned` instead.

Comment: When you say "Unicode" do you mean UTF-16 (as in `Encoding.Unicode`)? UTF-16 and UTF-8 are both encodings for the Unicode character set. They can both encode the all the codepoints in the character set. So, what do you mean by UTF-8 space?

Comment: Does C# support `[[:space:]]` for horizontal whitespace? Or `\h` same thing?

Comment: Steve that was a error, sorry

Comment: I'm reading a DataTable with culture Encoding.Default (UTF-8)

Comment: Looks like you just need `string pattern = @"[\u000D\u000A\u0009]+";` and `string replacement = " ";`. Please confirm you only need to replace a line break, carriage return and tab chars with a regular space (`\x20`)

Comment: In .NET all text datatypes use UTF-16. (That's not unique to .NET; It's the same for many other programming environments: Java, JavaScript, VB4-6,VBA,….) It doesn't matter where the text came from.

Comment: Check [this demo](https://ideone.com/d9jGR9).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Great! Works great! I'm really grateful with your help. I'm not so good with culture information and regular expressions. Thanks!

Comment: @DiegoFernandoBarriosOlmos If my solution works please consider accepting/upvoting my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex - `[^\u0020\u0009\u000D]+` - is a [*negated character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches any 1+ chars *other than* a regular space (`\u0020`), tab (`\u0009`) and carriage return (`\u000D`). You actually are looking for a positive character class that would match one of the three chars you indicated (`\x0A` for a newline, `\x0D` for a carriage return and `\x09` for a tab) in the question with a regular space (`\x20`).

You may just use

```
var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"[\x0A\x0D\x09]", " ");
```

See the [regex demo](https://ideone.com/d9jGR9)

Comment: You code work for me, I include  \u00A0:&nbsp in the string pattern.      string pattern = @"[\u0020\u0009\u000D\u00A0]+";
Thanks so much!

Comment: @DiegoFernandoBarriosOlmos If it works, please consider accepting.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you please explain the difference between ```\x09``` and ```\u0009```? As I understand regex will find the same symbol but the writing form is different, why? Thank you.

Comment: @RomanSimenok You are right, these are different hex notations representing the same*literal* symbol.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So you mean that there is no difference wich notation representation to use? I'm asking because I'm confused a little bit, I'm writing in Objective-C for iOS, and I can't put ```\u0009``` in regex, I'm getting an error like this is control character, but I can put ```\x09``` and it's working fine, is it ok?)

Comment: @RomanSimenok In Obj-C, string literals support different string escape sequences. You may pass `\uXXXX`  notation to the regex engine using a regex escape, i.e. make the ``\`` *literal* by doubling it, `@"\\u0009"`. See [this Obj-C demo](https://ideone.com/ts3yje). When you use `@"\x09"`, you pass an actual TAB char to the regex engine, not a hex entity.